# wrapping a youtube video in a static image "frame" and maintain responsive resizing

Tags: html, css, video, youtube, fitvids

I have the below image of a blank Macbook.

[image]

The image is 1034 × 543.

I want inset a youtube video inside of the "grey" area of the screen. I want it to appear as if the youtube video is playing on the laptop screen.

I also want the laptop image / youtube video to scale, so that when the web page is in a tablet or mobile view, the image and video shrink to match.

I am trying to use `fitvid.js` to accomplish this but am not having luck -- I can get the video to fit at one static size but I cannot get it to still fit perfectly on resize, it gets deformed.

Below is my current markup:

**html**:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="title">
    <h2>What's New</h2>
    <small>ASC Sneak Peak</small>
  </div>
  <div class="macbook-wrapper">
    <iframe width="715" height="402" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/**url**" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SASS**:

```
.macbook-wrapper{
  background: url('../img/content/home/macbook.png') no-repeat;

  .fluid-width-video-wrapper {
    width: 97.5%;
    background: #000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/41sdho4w/ ? Just wanted to make sure I understood your question correctly before posting an answer.

Comment: Awesome, I am sure there are a ton of ways to do it but this is how I would tackle it. @ My comment below, what I was saying is that you could build a macbook around the iframe out of CSS and have that scale too without all the positioning and super accurate padding.

Comment: is this responsive too?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could instill some trickery with padding and percentages, that way you could have it scale accordingly. Basically, setting up a container that's purely % base, with an absolutely position iframe that scales accordingly to the container.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 67.5%;
}
div iframe {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZNgk.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You'd just need to add `box-sizing: border-box;` and some `padding` to position the iframe within the screen. Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/41sdho4w/

To take it a bit further - here's a version with a container to help control the `max-width` and `max-height` rather then relying on the body / viewport http://jsfiddle.net/4g9e3ywy/

Comment: Hi! thanks for the great solution, it works but the macbook is 100% of the page width. I'd like it to scale downwards gracefully, but not exceed 1034x543. If I add max-width and max-height to the container div, it seems to mess with the iframe padding

Comment: My bad! let me update it, might just need a designated container that the % can be based off of.

Comment: I created an additional container for the entire thing - this is where you can set your desired max-width/max-height - and the children elements % padding / width, etc will rely on this.

Comment: Perfect. I actually realized the container trick just before checking back here to see your update. :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: great.. i just search for this type of thing.. +1 @Evan