# Change the dimensions of a fullscreen html5 video

Tags: javascript, css, html, video, angular

Is there a way to modify how the fullscreen functionality of a video behaves in a browser? I would like to display the video on the left side of my screen and an image (actually a PDF) on the right side.

I have tried it with css in chrome:

```
video:-webkit-full-screen
```

And that gave me some results, but not the desired one. Should I create a custom action for this? And if so, how can I let the video break out of the borders of the browsers?

Answer (score 1):

You should insert the `<video>` tag inside a `<div>` with a defined `height` and `width` with the following attributes:

```
.video-container {
   position: relative;
   height: auto;
   width: 60%;
}

video {
   width: 100%; 
   max-width: 500px; // Or whatever value on your choice
   height: auto;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

With a `width` of 100%, the video would fill the entire browser space but limit how big it can be by setting a `max-width` or `max-height` for the resolution and the responsiveness. I hope that my answer helps you!

**EDIT**

To fit in properly inside a `div`, you have to assign to the container `position: relative` and `position: absolute` to the video itself. If you want to break out from the borders, then you have to tweak the dimensions of `max-height` and `max-width`of the video.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573562/wrapping-a-youtube-video-in-a-static-image-frame-and-maintain-responsive-resiz), since it is similar to yours.

Comment: This will only take up the space in the browser, not of the screen itself.

Comment: I have modified my answer, check it out!

Comment: I have opted for another solution, the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API