# how to set embed video in a laptop image

Tags: css, wordpress, video, youtube, embed

I have this image of this laptop:

http://www.ildottoredellepiante.it/formazione/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/laptop-png-6754.png

And I would like to add it to the "section-743" of my website (right after slider on the top of the page) --> http://www.ildottoredellepiante.it and I would love to embed a video inside the blackside of the screen image. the video url is from youtube and is the following: www.youtube.com/watch?v=ucXRLnIkTyQ

Also, will it be working responsively?

I look forward to your reply geniuses :)

Comment: Can you share your code instead of your website ?

Comment: Well I wish I could, however I'm looking for the code....

Comment: I'm trying to do something very similar to this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573562/wrapping-a-youtube-video-in-a-static-image-frame-and-maintain-responsive-resiz

however I wouldn't know how to adjust this code for my website and where to put what.....sorry I'm a beginner and looking to learn. Any help is appreciated. The section where i'm trying to insert this code is "section-743" and I would love to know how to add this code in the editor of the template. It's complicated but with some Help I'm sure we can do this :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div>
        <div>
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/f890SC1schE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
       </div>
    </div>
```

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1034px;
    max-height: 543px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div div {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 67.5%;
    height: 0;
}
div iframe {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZNgk.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding: 11.9% 15.5% 14.8%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4g9e3ywy/

Hope it's helps.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your help. I can't see in the code where the youtube src will be....I'm a little confused. Can i add this code directly into section?

Comment: Hey Remy, Thank you for your response. I'm still having trouble. How can I add code directly on wordpress? thru editor or on page via text tab?

Comment: Just have to edit your style.css at the root of your template and your page source code throw the WYSIWYG when you edit your page (switch to text to source).

Comment: I'm still confused :( that code where should be entered in style.css....

Comment: I'm a beginner as I've said... :(

Comment: It will be hard for me to explain how to edit code more than I already did...sorry bro. Google it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/whilerests/whilerests1407/whilerests140700017/29617350-open-laptop-with-blank-screen-isolated-on-white-background.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="video">
    <video width="100%" muted autoplay>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support HTML video.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the css. maybe this will hep you.

```
.video-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1300px;
}

.video{
position: absolute;
    width: 883px;
    height: 530px;
    padding-top: 45px;
    background-color: #000;
    left: 650px;
    top: -2px;
    transform: translate(-50%, 28%);
}
.image{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
```